# PHP "if empty" help Joomla - VirtueMart

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with this code. If the field `customer_note` is empty, need it to return a value of `N` and `Y` if there is text in the field. The resulting `Y` or `N` is being passed into an XML line. I'm using PHP 5.2.9.

Thank you.

```
if( !empty( $customer_note )) {
  $shopper_message .= $customer_note."\n";
} else {
  $shopper_message .= "\n";
}
```

Comment: "Return" the value to where? The code you show seems very incomplete

Comment: What is `Y` or `N`? Does the code has something to do with your question? What is your concrete question/problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want this:

```
< ?php 
function check_ifempty($customer_note)
    {
        if (empty($customer_note)) 
        { 
  return "N"; 
 } 
 else 
 { 
  return "Y"; 
 } 
} 
?>

< ?php 
$customer_note = $_POST["customer_note"]; 
$result = check_ifempty($customer_note); 
$xml .= $result; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$has_customer_note = empty($customer_note) ? 'N' : 'Y';
```

Check out the part about return values of [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to see what is considered an empty value.

An alternative can be to use [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

```
$has_customer_note = strlen($customer_note) > 0 ? 'Y' : 'N';
```